ActiveMQ Classic web console fails to start: Could not open ServletContext resource
I have noticed an issue in the recent upgrade of ActiveMQ from 5.16.1 to 5.16.7 where the ActiveMQ web console fails to start with the below exception. Other functionality is working fine but can't launch the web console. No configuration changes were made in this upgrade from my end.
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI: /***/web-console/
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE: Service Unavailable
SERVLET: -

According to the exception below, I checked the file path and conf where the context pointed to the respective path and the file is available.
jetty.xml:
<bean id="secHandlerCollection" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <property name="handlers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                    <property name="contextPath" value="**/messagebus/web-console  "/>
                    <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin"/>
                    <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

Files
***/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-default.xml
***/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml

Exception
2024-04-24 15:41:17,563 | WARN  | Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@319c3a25{ActiveMQ Console,/server/web-console,file:///path/activemq/webapps/admin/,UNAVAILABLE} | org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext | main
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:232)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:203)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:679)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:562)
at org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter.createWebapplicationContext(WebConsoleStarter.java:71)
at org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter.contextInitialized(WebConsoleStarter.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1073)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1002)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:765)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:333)
... 78 more

Do we need to add any configuration changes to launch the web console?

Note: Jetty 11 and older (which is what you are running according to your stacktrace) is now at End of Community Support, you should be using Jetty 12 at this point in time.

Jetty is packed as part of ActiveMQ tarball which was utilized here and changing it might break its compatibility. I hope the Jetty version doesn't relate to this issue.

It's worth noting that ActiveMQ Classic 5.16.x is also no longer maintained so you should upgrade ASAP.

I noticed that there is already a ticket open for this.
ISSUE:
It's not directly related to ActiveMQ Classic. It's due to an upgrade of Jetty which has some fixes that restrict the symbolic reference usage. ( /opt/app-1 -> /opt/app)
FIX:
Referring to actual reference (/opt/app-1) instead of symbolic reference (/opt/app) will also fix the issue.
Instead, there is a way to fix this issue in jetty.xml, e.g.:
...
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" />
   <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
   <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />

   <!-- add here. start -->
   <property name="aliasChecks">
      <list>
         <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApproveAliases"/>
      </list>
   </property>
   <!-- end -->
</bean>


I had the same problem. The issue was that I was setting the ACTIVEMQ_HOME environment variable to a hard coded value in the run script activemq. My path had a link as well. I think the main issue is that you need to let the script activemq use getActiveMQhome to figure out the path. When I removed the line exporting the ACTIVEMQ_HOME variable,  it got the right path without the link. and ActiveMQ ran fine.
Also, don't modify jetty.xml to use a hard coded path. If you see an area where it uses ${activemq.home}, do not replace it with a path.
